# What is the reason to use a suffix on database table and/or column names?

Tags: database

This question is out of pure curiosity.

Why do some systems and frameworks adopt a suffix on table and/or column names?

Example: the [Activiti](http://www.activiti.org/) framework for business process uses the `_` character at the end of every column name (ID_, VERSION_, NAME_, ...). I have notice that in some other systems as well.

I'm sure there is a good reason for that.

Comment: Namespacing, I guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a convention for using names that can be saved words. When you want to call column "from" you can use "from_" because "from" is saved word of SQL.

Comment: ok thanks, that makes sense. Sorry if the question was too stupid.